# Lock screen app in C# for windows

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

**Hey guys**,I have made a face recognition application using C# and matlab in visual studio 2013 and I want it to run in lock screen before i entered my password can i do that using C#?

Comment: I suspect this won't be easy in any language. Perhaps the only way it could work is to do it like the vendors of finger-print scanners on notebooks. I.e. you would probably have to write a driver that is doing this job.

Comment: Maybe if you make your application to run as a service and configure it to start automatically with a specific logon (on control panel / services) would be a starting point. But i understand there are other obstacles.

Comment: Would be quite hard, a workaround(sort of) would be disabling all the keyboard keys and setting the app as a fullscreen app so aslong as its running theres no way to access desktop apart from closing the app(the face recognition does)